# Create a new release without buildID via powershell with VSTeam

Tags: powershell

I want to create a new release, I have a release definition but I don't have buildID and I don't need to.
When I run this there is no build ID

```
Get-VSTeamReleaseDefinition -Id 2936 -raw
```

I am trying to create the release like this:

```
Add-VSTeamRelease -DefinitionId 2936 -ArtifactAlias {""}
```

BuildID is required. How can I create without it?

The release definition has stages that I want to select only one and 3 variables that I need to insert manually via the UI. I want to do this with my script. Any suggestions?
In any case build ID is not required when I run the 'Create Release'

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Nir, Please add your code here instead of put just two line!!

Comment: This is the code. Don’t need more then one line…just asking about the build I’d and the rest parameters that I need to supply